# Multiprocessing, Pool.map()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I don't understand how it works. I have function **log_in** with two arguments **user** and **password**. And have **list** with all my users and passwords. So, when I using **p.map(log_in, list)**, it's means that list will iterate and "unpack". Where ['user','bitnami'], ['user1', '12345'] etc will be these arguments **log_in**(***user***, ***password***).
Yes?

```
def log_in(user, password):
        payload = wrap_creds_in_xml(username=user, password=password)
        response = requests.post(TARGET_URL, payload)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TARGET_URL = 'http://192.168.1.6/wp-login.php'
    list = [['user', 'bitnami'], ['user1', '12345'],
            ['user2', '54321'], ['user3', 'qwerty']]
    p = Pool(5)
    p.map(log_in, list)
```

And I have error

> TypeError: main() missing 1 required positional argument: 'password'

Comment: The error message suggests this isn't the case...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that `log_in` is a function that takes two arguments, but your code passes just a single argument to that function: a list with two elements. Try [`Pool.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap) instead of `Pool.map`:

```
p.starmap(log_in, list)
```

From the documentation of `Pool.starmap()`:

> Like `map()` except that the elements of the iterable are expected to be
>   iterables that are unpacked as arguments.
>
> Hence an iterable of `[(1,2), (3, 4)]` results in `[func(1,2), func(3,4)]`.

Comment: While this works for some cases, it's unfortunate that `Pool.istarmap` and `Pool.istarmap_unordered` don't exist.